# ASP viewstate always contains invalid characters

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

I'm having problems with one of our ASP websites when I try to run it locally.
The problems have appeared since my laptop crashed this afternoon. Since then the view state is always invalid. The cause is clear: Any time I visit the homepage and inspect the viewstate input tag in my webpage, it contains invalid characters which are displayed in firebug as a diamond with a question mark inside it. Whenever I submit the page, of course, I get an error screen.

Since then I've tried the following:

- Restart my laptop
- Delete the temporary ASP files folder
- Stop/Start IIS
- Recycle the application pool
- Remove the website from IIS, delete all the source code, check out the source code from TFS, and rebuild the solution

The website does run fine on my colleague's PC with the same source code.

If anyone has any suggestions, please let me know!

EDIT: It happens to TWO of the websites I'm trying to run.
All the others I try run correctly

Comment: MSDN also suggest to try these things:1. Adjust the settings on the application pools so that recycling is less likely to occur at peak periods.
2. Use a specific key in the machine.config to prevent automatic key generation on each process start
3. Only post to the same ASPX page
4. Turn off firewall and antivirus software
My only other two questions are if it happens in all browsers for you or just one (e.g. is the browser your using garbling something)?And if your source code has become corrupted (assuming you're using source control of some kind if you get a latest copy if it still exists)

Comment: I get it on all browsers, and yes, I've already removed my source code and retrieved the latest version from source control.